# Why does my http request in Cloud9 always return an error?

Tags: javascript, cloud9-ide

I am currently developing a Cloud9 plugin, where I need to make a GET request to a remote web server. The following code is what I use to perform the request:

```
var http = imports.http;
http.request(url, {}, function(err, data, res) {
    if(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

When I perform the same GET request in a web browser, valid JSON is returned. However, using this code, I always receive an Error object, which tells me that the number of loaded bytes is 0. What is going wrong?

Comment: try asking on https://community.c9.io/ and showing more of the code you use. Someone of the developers may be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I received from the c9 community is the following: The reason is an unpermitted cross origin request (the URL points to a java servlet running on the same host inside a jetty server). The solution is therefore to include an Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header in the servlet's Response.